# How to manage a stream in order to process incoming data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

For each line in a file, I want to execute a computationally intensive task, such as image compression. The problem I have is that the data comes in too fast and overwhelms the memory. Ideally I'd like to be able to pause and continue the stream as the data gets processed.

I initially tried using the `readline` module with a file stream like this:

```
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('long-list.txt')
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: fileStream })
rl.on('line', (line, lineCount) => {
   doTheHeavyTask(line)
})
```

However, this quickly overwhelms the memory with thousands of calls to `doTheHeavyTask()`.

I settled on pushing each line into a queue and creating an event that dequeues the next line when the previous line is done being processed:

```
const lineQ = new Queue() // From the 'queue-fifo' module
rl.on('line', (line, lineCount) => {
   lineQ.enqueue(line)
})
const lineEmitter = new EventEmitter() // From the 'events' module
lineEmitter.on('processNextLine', async () => {
    await doTheHeavyTask( lineQ.dequeue() )
    if (!lineQ.isEmpty()) lineEmitter.emit('processNextLine')
})
setTimeout( () => lineEmitter.emit('processNextLine'), 20) // Give rl a moment to enqueue some lines
```

This works, but it seems kind of hacky and not much better than just reading in the file all at once.

I'm vaguely aware of concepts like "backpressure" and "generators" in Javascript, but I'm not sure how to apply them.

Comment: Is `doHeavyTask` async?

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, `doTheHeavyTask` is async. But even if it were synchronous, I believe `rl` will keep emitting the `'line'` event as fast as it can read in the file.

Comment: no. it would not. JS has an *observably synchronous execution model*. No code will run at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not the stream itself, but the async task that you trigger. Every task (wether it is a callback with a closure or an async function) will consume memory. If you start multiple (thousand) tasks at the same time, that'll use resources.

You can use an async iterator to go over the lines, and do one task for each (and wait for it):

```
 (async function () {
     for await (const el of rl) {
        await doHeavyTask(el);
     }
 })();
```

That'll correctly backpressure.

However, it only does *one task at a time*, which might be quite slow. To buffer a few elements and process them concurrently, you could do:

```
 const SIZE = 10; // to be tested with different values

 (async function () {
   let chunk = [];
   for await(const el of rl) {
      chunk.push(el);
      if(chunk.length >= SIZE) {
         await Promise.all(chunk.map(doHeavyTask));
         chunk.length = 0;
      }
   }
   await Promise.all(chunk.map(doHeavyTask));
})();
```

*You need [at least Node 11.14.0](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator) for this to work*.

Comment: Any ideas how to do something similar in Node 10?

Comment: polyfilling that won't be fun.

Comment: Or to be more specific: Handling backpressure / closing of streams correctly is complicated. Better to use the official asyncIterator here, as it does all that correctly.

Comment: Looking at the `readline` [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) I bet I could make use of the `pause()` and `resume()` functions with their respective events. However the async iterator is far more idiomatic

Comment: Yes, something like `rl.on("line", async el => { rl.pause(); await doHeavyTask(el); rl.resume(); });` might work. Here's the [official way](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2bdeb88c27b4d8de3a8f6b7a438cf0bcb88fa927/lib/readline.js#L1087)

Comment: After trying it, `rl.on("line", async el => { rl.pause(); await doHeavyTask(el); rl.resume(); });` [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556863/is-there-a-way-to-actually-pause-readline) :,(
async iterator is the way to go

Comment: Oh, well, then my statement about backpressure is not that accurate. It'll buffer all the lines. That's not optimal, maybe you should do what Benjamin suggests (using fs.readFile & split on \n) to correctly handle backpressure (on the filesystem level)